# Angular 2 page reload rather than consoling that we signup or signed in

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am working now on learning routes by doing a signup and signin forms and connect to firebase.

Here is the routes.ts file that specify each route:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SigninComponent } from './auth/signin/signin.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './auth/signup/signup.component';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo:'/signup', pathMatch:'full'},
    {path: 'signin', component: SigninComponent},
    {path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Then here is the signup form and it's typescript file:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
<form (ngSubmit)="onSignup(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password" ngModel>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    <a [routerLink]="['/signin']">You already have an account ? Sign In</a>

</div>
```

Signup.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import {AuthService} from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSignup(form: NgForm){
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;

    this.authService.signupUser(email, password);
  }

}
```

As you see I have the onSignup() function.

And the same for the signin component:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
<form (ngSubmit)="onSignin(f)" #f="ngForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="Password" id="Password" ngModel>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign In</button>
</form>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
    <a [routerLink]="['/signup']">Click to register</a>
</div>

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSignin(form: NgForm)
  {
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    this.authService.signinUser(email, password);
  }
}
```

The authentication service file script containing the `signinUser()` and `singupUser()` methods:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
export class AuthService {
    signupUser(email: string, password: string)
    {
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .catch(
                error=>console.log(error)
            )
    }

    signinUser(email: string, password: string)
    {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(
                response => console.log(response)
            )
            .catch(
                error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when I am signing up a new user, the all page is reloaded and nothing added to firebase database.

So I created manually a user on firebase, and tried the sign in form, and again the page is reloaded and nothing appears in the console (No output, No errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this issue and was tearing my hair out for an hour. 
The reason a properly configured form will reload the page on submit is that there is an error in the onSubmit() method in your ts file.
This one was hard to trace back because the problem was actually in my initializeApp method. Be sure the object you are passing with the apiKey and authDomain is correct. In my case I had typed

```
{api: "...mykey...", authDomain: "...myurl..."}
```

instead of api**Key**.
Also be sure you copy your auth url correctly. Don't put the http:// in front.

So the sign in and sign up methods don't know what url and api key to use because the initialization never completed correctly and got stored in the SDK. I hope this helps get to the bottom of your issue.